# Get JSON array from JSON array Java android

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, arraylist

I've got an JSON array, and I would like to select the data from it. I would like to get all subjects, but I don't know how to do it.

Code:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(thatarray);
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("response");
int arrSize = jsonArray.length();
List<Integer> sub = new ArrayList<Integer>(arrSize);

for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; ++i) {
    jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    System.out.println("Output: " + jsonObject.toString());
}
```

Comment: You want to get list of all subject ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually "response" is jsonObject and "data" is jsonArray..
u can differentiate between jsonArray and jsonObject by viewing {} and []...
hope it will help :)

I tried below code myself on your JSON and it is working.

```
 try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(thatarray);
        jsonObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("response");
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");

        JSONArray jsonArraysubject;
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length() - 1; i++) {
            jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            jsonArraysubject = jsonObject.getJSONArray("subjects");

            Log.d("MyLog", jsonArraysubject + "");
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```